# Referring to a top-level type being shadowed by local module type

Tags: f#

New to F#. Enjoying it.

I'm trying to refer to a type that I've declared in the top level of an F# module from within a nested module.

In this code I want `o1` to refer to the top-level `Order` type:

```
module Order

type Id = Id of int64
module Id = let value (Id i) = i // allow us to unpack the int64

type Order = {Id : Id}

module DTO =

  type Order = {Id : int64} 

  let DomainToDTO (o1 : Order) : Order = { Order.Id = Id.value(o1.Id) }
```

This works:

```
module Order

type Id = Id of int64
module Id = let value (Id i) = i // allow us to unpack the 

type Order1 = {Id : Id}

module DTO =

  type Order2 = {Id : int64} 

  let DomainToDTO (o1 : Order1) : Order2 = { Order2.Id = Id.value(o1.Id) }
```

Is it possible to tell the compiler that the DomainToDTO function expects to receive the top-level type, without giving the local type a different name?

I.e. I want code further down to either refer to "Order" or to "DTO.Order"?

Thanks for the help

Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to alias the type before shadowing it in the submodule:

```ml
module Order

type Id = Id of int64
module Id = let value (Id i) = i // allow us to unpack the int64

type Order = {Id : Id}

module DTO =
  type ParentOrder = Order
  type Order = {Id : int64} 

  let DomainToDTO (o1 : ParentOrder) : Order = { Order.Id = Id.value(o1.Id) }
```